# How to create a dynamic route with Svelte (not SvelteKit)?

Tags: svelte

I'm new to Svelte and I'm using `svelte-navigator` as a router. I could pass a fetch and make an API call to read all posts. But, I'm getting stuck on how to create a dynamic route that goes to a specific post to read it, edit it, and delete it later. Here is my code and I really appreciate your help;

**routes/index.svelte**:

```html
<Route path="posts/*">
   <Route path="/">
      <Home />
   </Route>
   <Route path=":id"> <PostDetail /> </Route>
</Route>
```

**PostDetail.svelte**:

```html
    export let post = [];

    onMount(async () => {

        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/posts/${post.id}/`)
        post = await response.json()

    });
```

**Home.svelte**:

```html
    let posts = [];

    onMount(async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/posts/`)
        posts = await response.json()
    });
    
   <div class = "col-md-8">
       {#each posts as post }
            <article class="card mb-3">
                <h4 class="card-title">
                     <Link class = "text-dark" to = {`/posts/${post.id}`}> { post.name } </Link>
                </h4>
                <p class="card-text text-break"> { post.description.slice(0, 250) } ... </p>
            </article>
       {:else}
           <p class = "text-center"> Loading ... </p>
       {/each}           
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://github.com/mefechoel/svelte-navigator#route) explains how to use parameters:

> A `Route` path can match parameters with `"path/:parameterName"` and wildcards with `"path/*"` or `"path/*wildcardName"`. All parameters and wildcard values will be provided to the `component` as props. They can also be accessed inside a `Route` slot via `let:params`.
>
> ```html
> <Route path="blog/:id" component="{BlogPost}" />
> <Route path="blog/:id" let:params>
>   <BlogPost id="{params.id}" />
> </Route>
> ```

So you either need to pass `PostDetail` as the `conponent` of `Route` or use `let:params` to pass on the `id` as a prop.

`PostDetail` needs to declare the `id` as prop (`export let id`).